# Pasar línea por línea a lista

Tags: python, python-requests

Tengo archivo TXT donde son multiples líneas, cada línea con tiene datos como los siguientes

```
1,1,1,13,2,4,2,3,1,12,0
3,12,3,2,3,11,4,5,2,5,1
1,9,4,6,1,4,3,2,3,9,1
```

Necesito meter cada línea en una lista, para que quede de la siguiente manera

```
[1,1,1,13,2,4,2,3,1,12,0]
[3,12,3,2,3,11,4,5,2,5,1]
[1,9,4,6,1,4,3,2,3,9,1]
```

El código que he intentado es el siguiente, pero devuelve el contendido en una sola lista.

```
archivo = open('C:/Users/israe/Documents/Maestria/dataset/dataset.txt')
lista=[(archivo.read().splitlines())]

print(lista)
```

Comment: Podrías añadir el código que has intentado?

Comment: listo, añadí el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez abierto un archivo, puedes iterar por él y cada iteración te devuelve una línea, por lo que no necesitas hacer lo de `.read().splitlines()`, que además es ineficiente porque requiere leer el archivo completo a memoria, mientras que iterar por él solo necesita leer una línea de cada vez.

En tu caso basta aplicarle a esa línea las operaciones necesarias para dividir por la coma, que sería `.split(",")` (con lo que obtendrías una lista, pero de cadenas, como `["1", "1", "3", ...etc]`) y después aplicar a cada elemento de esa lista la operación `int()` para convertirlo en un entero.

Algo como esto:

```
with open("fichero.txt") as f:
  for linea in f:
    datos = [int(n) for n in linea.split(",")]
    print(datos)
```

En cada iteración del bucle `datos` será una lista como la que pides.